# In the dice throwing experiment, calculate the conditional probability...

Tags: probability, statistics

In the dice throwing experiment, calculate the conditional probability of $A = \{1, 2\}$ given the events $B_1 = \{4, 5, 6\}, B_2 = \{1, 5, 6\}, B_3 = \{1, 2, 6\}$

$P(A|B_1) = \frac{P(A ∩ B_1)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{P(∅)}{1/2}= 0$

I don't understand why $P(B_1)=1/2$ and also why that division equals to zero.

Comment: $P(B_1)$ is not $0$ but $P(A\cap B_1)$ clearly is $0$.

Comment: @lulu I know. It's 1/2 but I don't understand why

Comment: There are $6$ equiprobable events, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  $B_1$ comprises exactly half of them.

Comment: @lulu I understood $P(A∩B_1)$,  it's zero because $A$ and $B_1$ have no elements in common, but why is $P(B_1)=1/2$? The zero I'm talking about in the question is the result.

Comment: Crossed comments.  Do you see why my prior comment shows that $P(B_1)=\frac 12$?

Comment: @lulu ok now I understand why it's 1/2. The result is zero because $0/0.5=0$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Note:  I am not sure what you mean by "odds condition".  But $P(A\,|\,B_1)$ is certainly $0$.

Comment: I strongly suspect that "*odds condition*" is a mistranslation of the actual phrase "*conditional probability.*"  Note, the word "odds" is *related* to the word "probability" however they are not interchangeable and mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Note that $B_1$ contains $3$ distinct independent outcomes out of $6$ possible equi-probable outcomes. Also when $B_1$ happens, there is no chance that $A$ can happen either since **no element of the probability space $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ belongs to both $A$ and $B_1$**.